# need help in choosing a pc to run my flash-kiosk-app on - what cpu factors affect flash performance?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, cpu, kiosk

i am a self-taught actionscript 3 programmer and i have written a gaming-app to run on an all-in-one touchscreen pc in fullscreen kiosk mode. this project is a "garage business" meaning i learn as i go and i dont have any of the resources of a full company ("only" a great idea and a great app).

my question regards flash/air cpu needs, multicore, clockspeed and such

the app will run on Adobe AIR, and it is not heavy on computing but rather heavy on screen rendering. Since flash/AIR rely almost completely on the cpu for the graphics rendering (and not the graphics card) i need a pc that will most suit me. i do not live in the states and i have to choose a pc based on specs alone (and custom-order it).

currently i am developing the app on Flash cs4 on my old dual 2.3 ppc mac (and on it the app doesnt run quick enough).

- i am most interested in a Sony Vaio L VPCL116FX/B that has an Intel® Core™ 2 Quad Q8400S (2.66GHz) processor but it is backordered and will MAYBE be available next month.
- another option is a VPCL111FX/B Vaio L which is in stock, but has a weaker cpu (Intel® Pentium® E5400 (2.70GHz))
- a third option is an HP touchsmart 600-1055 which has an 2.13GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Processor P7450

time is crucial since the kiosk must be up and running on March 24th. so i have to decide quickly.

my questions:
since flash/air are not multi-threaded should i even wait for the Q8400s?
is clockspeed the factor that will most determine the app performace? in that case, is the "weakest" Pentium® E5400 the best choice? (it has a 2.7Ghz cpu)
is "core 2" much more stronger then a Pentium, and the hp's P7450 is the best choice?

i know the info is very lacking but i would like help nevertheless

thanx a lot,
Saar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely avoid Pentium, it was developed with GHz as the only requirement, no matter how badly it performed.  Almost any Core2 will outperform almost any pentium; the only exception i can think would be an old 'server style' pentium mainboard with fat busses and fast RAM outperforming a laptop-style core2 machine, with slow RAM.  I don't think the Vaio L is such a beast.